# Caching dynamically loaded images

Tags: javascript, html, caching, image

I'm using javascript to dynamically load any of a series of images into a single img tag, based on user interaction:

```
function reassignImage(newSource)
{
   img.src = newSource;
}
```

This works great, except that I when I inspect it with Chrome developer tools,
I see that even if I reload an image I've already loaded, it makes another http call AND grows the total Images Size graph.

This seems like the worst of both worlds.  I would want either:

1. To load from cache if the image were
   the same.
2. To reload each image
   everytime, but then not grow the
   cache.

How would I achieve either scenario?

Thanks! Yarin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will pre-load an image so that the browser can display it immediately when you actually set the `src` of an `img` tag. I speculate that pre-loading an image like this will ensure it's in the cache so it won't reload, though I haven't tested it.

```
var myImg = new Image(25, 25);
myImg.src = "/foobar.png";
```

In other words, this should now hopefully only download two images

```
function reassignImage(newSource) {
    var myImg = new Image(25, 25);
    myImg.src = newSource;
    img.src = newSource;
}

reassignImage("first.png");
reassignImage("second.png");
reassignImage("first.png");
```

**Edit**

I was doing it wrong. Try creating a `new Image()` for every new file the user loads. Swap these image elements in and out of the dom.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
    var imageElements = {};
    function reassignImage(newSource) {
      if (typeof imageElements[newSource] == "undefined") {
        imageElements[newSource] = new Image();
        imageElements[newSource].src = newSource;
      }
      var container = document.getElementById("imageContainer");
      container.innerHTML = '';
      container.appendChild(imageElements[newSource]);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="imageContainer"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Dave- not sure I follow.  Are you saying that by creating the actual Image tag dynamically, it effects how images are cached?  And the second part of your example is unclear- why do you assign the newSource to two diff img components?

Comment: @Yarin `new Image` doesn't create an image _tag_ it creates an image _object_. This is the party approved way to pre-load images. I'm guessing that using these image objects will affect how the image files are cached, yes. `myImg.src = newSource` assigns the `src` of an image _object_ while `img.src = newSource` assigns the `src` of your image _tag_.

Comment: @Dave- OK Interesting I hadn't realized the concept of Image objects.  However, still confused by the example- what do we DO with the Image object you created- shouldn't we assign it to img.src?

Comment: @Yarin, on second thought, I think you're right. `new Image` is the same type as document.getElementById("myImageId"). I suspect my answer is useless. Sorry about that!

Comment: Actually that gives me another idea. Hold on a second, I'll put it together and edit my answer.

Answer (score 5):

What's the cache-control header set to in the http response for the image?  (Chrome developer tools will show you).  If it's not set to be cacheable, it will get refetched.

Comment: good point here- so a follow up question is how do you control cache-control headers off of something like Amazon Cloudfront or other CDNs?

Comment: Not sure about cloudfront, but Amazon S3 allows you to set any header you like when you upload - I would imagine CDNs do too.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can set it this way in `.htaccess` file:

```
# Set up caching on images for 1 month
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|ico|gif)$">
ExpiresDefault A2419200
</FilesMatch>
```

If you would like with this settings force image to refresh, append this to its URL:

```
'?'+ new Date().getTime()
```