# Function keeps requesting images from server instead of the cache

Tags: jquery, browser-cache

I have created an animation using a JQuery "slideshow". The function flips through 62 images with a speed set at 100 milliseconds. The problem is, that Chrome developer tools shows, that the function keeps requesting the images from the server over and over again for each cycle, instead of using the cache.
The pictures all have the same size of 32.2 KB and also have the same dimensions. There are about 20 of these animations on the website which you can see a test version of here: [link](http://fiskervej.com/tody/). The animations are the 20 small indicators, placed in the big blue area in the middle of the page.

The code can be seen below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">      

function slideShow(id, index, imagePath, lastImage, fadeTime) {

     $('#slideShowBack'+id).show();
     index = (index == lastImage) ? 1 : index + 1;
     $("#slideShowBack"+id).attr("src", imagePath + "/" + index + ".png")
     setTimeout('slideShow(' + '"'+ id + '"' + ',' + index + ',' + '"'+ imagePath + '"' +', ' + lastImage + ', ' +  fadeTime + ')', fadeTime);
  }

   $(document).ready(function() {
     slideShow('SovSeng', 1, 'images', 62, 100);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <img id="slideShowBackSovSeng"  src="" />
```

I also tried a different approach This successfully only requests the images from the server during the first cycle, but while doing the first cycle it flickers/blinks very noticeably between images.

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 

     var imagePath = "images";
     var lastImage = 62;
     var removeAfter = 100;

     function slideShow(index) {
        var url = imagePath + "/" + index + ".png";
        $("#slideShow").prepend($("<img/>").attr("src",url));
        $("#slideShow img:last").remove();
           setTimeout(function() {
              slideShow((index % lastImage) + 1)
           }, removeAfter);
     }

     $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() { slideShow(1); }, removeAfter);
     });

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
       <div id="slideShow">
          <img id="slideShow" src="images/1.png" />
       </div>
```

I then tried using a function to preload the images and this works perfectly most of the time in Chrome, but after the the page has just been loaded, the slideshow function will sometimes randomly start fetching the images directly from the server, instead of preloading them. I have placed the preload before the slideshow code. The preload never works on Firefox, Internet Explorer or Edge. I have not tried Safari.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function preloadImages(array) {
   if (!preloadImages.list) {
      preloadImages.list = [];
   }
   var list = preloadImages.list;
   for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function() {
         var index = list.indexOf(this);
         if (index !== -1) {
            list.splice(index, 1);
         }
      }
      list.push(img);
      img.src = array[i];
   }
}

preloadImages(["images/1.png", "images/2.png", "images/3.png", etc.. ]); 

</script>
```

So my question is can i stop my function in the first code example making infinite requests to the server or alternatively can i improve my code in my second example so that it stops flickering/blinking doing the first run?

Edit: HTTP headers of a image request from the function in the first code example.

I am not totally sure anymore that the request bypasses the cache, as Chrome Dev Tools shows that the amount of data transferred is not actually going up, after the first run through of the animation. What am i missing here, are the http requests being redirected to the cache?

```
    {
    "startedDateTime": "2017-04-11T21:05:11.260Z",
    "time": 0,
    "request": {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "http://fiskervej.com/tody/images/31.png",
      "httpVersion": "unknown",
      "headers": [],
      "queryString": [],
      "cookies": [],
      "headersSize": -1,
      "bodySize": 0
    },
    "response": {
      "status": 200,
      "statusText": "OK",
      "httpVersion": "unknown",
      "headers": [
        {
          "name": "Date",
          "value": "Tue, 11 Apr 2017 21:02:44 GMT"
        },
        {
          "name": "Last-Modified",
          "value": "Wed, 05 Apr 2017 04:49:17 GMT"
        },
        {
          "name": "Server",
          "value": "Apache"
        },
        {
          "name": "Accept-Ranges",
          "value": "bytes"
        },
        {
          "name": "Content-Length",
          "value": "33266"
        },
        {
          "name": "Content-Type",
          "value": "image/png"
        }
      ],
      "cookies": [],
      "content": {
        "size": 33266,
        "mimeType": "image/png"
      },
      "redirectURL": "",
      "headersSize": -1,
      "bodySize": 0,
      "_transferSize": 0
    },
    "cache": {},
    "timings": {
      "blocked": -1,
      "dns": -1,
      "connect": -1,
      "send": 0,
      "wait": 0,
      "receive": 0,
      "ssl": -1
    },
    "serverIPAddress": "144.208.78.49",
    "pageref": "page_1"
  },
```

Comment: Can you show us HTTP headers of a image request and response that browser doesn't cache? You can use Chrom DevTools [Copy All as HAR](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#copy).

Comment: Hi @LeonidVasilyev thanks for the reply. I have added an example of an image request. I used Chrome DevTools "Copy All as HAR".

Comment: This might be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712234/caching-dynamically-loaded-images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misinterpreted network information. Images are properly cached. But looking at animation we talking about, DOM based JavaScript animation may not be the best choice.

Despite of lack of explicit freshness information like `Cache-Control` and `Expires` HTTP headers in response, browser still caches it using heuristic freshness. Response's `bodySize` equals to 0 means that it comes from cache. Probably you can see (from disk cache) label in size column of Chrome Dev Tools Network tab. Also some requests may hit so called [List of available images](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-list-of-available-images) or in memory cache.

It seems to me that in your case all these DOM manipulations can be replaced with single animated GIF file and single `img` node. There are many other ways to do animation for the Web. You may want to check [What's the best way to animate an illustration for the web?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/39613/whats-the-best-way-to-animate-an-illustration-for-the-web) discussion on Graphic Design Stack Exchange.

For more information check:

- [HAR 1.2 Spec](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-12-spec/) by Jan Odvarko
- [The State of Browser Caching, Revisited](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2017/03/16/browser-caching) by Mark Nottingham
- [HTTP Caching](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching) by lya Grigorik

Comment: Thank you @Leonid for your help. I changed the animations to gif's and this works much better.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried server side and client side caching? I'd look into them both.

The DOM will all ways get loaded first before any javascript is executed so what you could do is load the images and hide them from view using CSS and then when the scripts get executed all the images should be loaded.

I looked into caching dynamically loaded images and came across  `new Image()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712234/caching-dynamically-loaded-images)